# Vue test utils: extend VueWrapper to add plugin method

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

I am using [Vue test utils](https://github.com/vuejs/test-utils) and Typescript. I have added [Data Test ID Plugin](https://test-utils.vuejs.org/guide/extending-vtu/plugins.html#data-test-id-plugin).

How can I extend [VueWrapper](https://github.com/vuejs/test-utils/blob/8fdb38e1af95bad6ed9f44dfa88f1a97451dcf7e/src/vueWrapper.ts) interface to avoid this error:

```
Property 'findByTestId' does not exist on type 'VueWrapper<{ $: ComponentInternalInstance; $data: { showUserMenu: boolean ...
```

Comment: The question is unanswerable without package versions of `vue`, `vue-test-utils`, `jest`, `typescript` and a few more deps, depending on whether you're using `@vue/cli` or `vite`. Ideally you should provide a *runnable* [mcve] (on codesandbox.io or similar).

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to export a type that adds `findByTestId`:

```js
// my-vue-test-utils-plugin.ts
import { config, DOMWrapper, createWrapperError, type VueWrapper } from '@vue/test-utils'
               
export type TestWrapper = VueWrapper<any> & {
  findByTestId: (selector: string) => DOMWrapper<HTMLElement>
}

const DataTestIdPlugin = (wrapper: VueWrapper<any>) => {
  function findByTestId(selector: string) {
    const dataSelector = `[data-testid='${selector}']`
    const element = wrapper.element.querySelector(dataSelector)
    if (element) {
      return new DOMWrapper(element)
    }

    return createWrapperError('DOMWrapper')
  }

  return {
    findByTestId
  }
}

config.plugins.VueWrapper.install(DataTestIdPlugin as any)
```

Then, use [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) (`as` keyword followed by the exported type above) on the `mount()` result:

```js
// MyComponent.spec.ts
import type { TestWrapper } from './my-vue-test-utils-plugin.ts'

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  it('renders properly', () => {        
    const wrapper = mount(MyComponent) as TestWrapper
    expect(wrapper.findByTestId('my-component').text()).toBe('Hello World')
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to create a `.d.ts` file e.g. `vue-test-utils.d.ts` with the following content:

```js
import { DOMWrapper } from '@vue/test-utils';

declare module '@vue/test-utils' {
  export class VueWrapper {
    findByTestId(selector: string): DOMWrapper[];
  }
}
```

So you're able to extend the existing definition of the `VueWrapper` class.